# pop up in samsung smart TV

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, samsung-smart-tv

I need help here I'm using this in js

```
$('#popup').sfPopup({
        text: 'Would You like to close this popup?',
        buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
        defaultFocus: 1,    // index of default focused button. this indicates array index of 'buttons' option (zero-based)
        callback: function (selectedIndex) {
            alert('selected button index: ' + selectedIndex);
        }
    });
    $('#popup').sfPopup('show');
```

};

and this in html

```
<div id='popup'></div>
```

i found this example here

http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/api_reference/appsframework_apis/ui_components_api/uiapi_popup_sfpopup.html

but it's not working what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

There could be some problems with z-index. Try this after sfPopup:

```
$('#popup').css('z-index','10000');
```

Comment: still not working i fell that i have to define something or include something to be able to use sfPopup i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Are you using App Framework ? Also try including 2 scripts in the page header:

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/core.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/ui.js'></script>
```

I think it should work if u use App Framework. In my case I got error "`sfLang undefined`" but that's prolly cos I am not using App Framework.

Comment: i'm not using the app framework so i build my own popup, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the AppFramework script in the index.html of your project

`<script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/af/2.0.0/loader.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need

```
$('#popup').sfPopup('focus');
```

after the  `$('#popup').sfPopup('show');`

Comment: And you would want to associate the popup with a key pressed or an event.